# Finding the Transformation of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am working on learning how to solve matrix problems similar to this one and would appreciate an example if someone were willing to walk me through it.

> Let T: $R^2$ -> $R^3$ Have the standard matrix
>   $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1\space\space\space\space\ \ 2 \\ 2\space\ -1 \\ 1 \space\space\space\space\space\ \ 0  \end{bmatrix} $$ 
>    B is the basis $B$ = $ \{\ \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \ \ ,\ \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ -1  \end{bmatrix} \ \}\ of \space R^2 $$ 
> \quad \text {C is the Basis} \ C = $$ \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\} \space of \space R^3$ Find the matrix for $T$ relative to the Bases $B$ and $C$

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $T(1,1)=T(1,0)+T(0,1)=(1,2,1)+(2,-1,0)=(3,1,1)$.
Now you need to find the vector $(3,1,1)$ w.r.t. the basis $C$. Thus you need to solve the following system of equations:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&\mid&3\\
0&1&1&\mid&1\\
1&1&0&\mid&1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&\mid&3\\
0&1&1&\mid&1\\
0&1&-1&\mid&-2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&\mid&\frac{3}{2}\\
0&1&0&\mid&-\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&1&\mid&\frac{3}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Hence $(3,1,1)=\frac{3}{2}(1,0,1)-\frac{1}{2}(0,1,1)+\frac{3}{2}(1,1,0)$. It follows that the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the bases $B$ and $C$ is given by $$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{2}&*\\
-\frac{1}{2}&*\\
\frac{3}{2}&*
\end{pmatrix}$$.

Find the second column yourself. The key is to remember that the matrix of a transformation $P$ w.r.t. the bases $A$ and $B$ is given by the following procedure:

Find $P(a_i)$ ($P$ applied to the $i$-th basisvector of $A$). Write $P(a_i)=\sum_{j}\lambda_{ji}b_j$. That is, write $P(a_i)$ w.r.t. the basis $B$. The coefficients $\lambda_{ji}$ make up the $i$-th column of the matrix that we are looking for.

Comment: One could, of course, compute the entire matrix at once by augmenting $C$ with both columns of $TB$ instead of doing them one at a time. Both row-reductions will involve exactly the same operations, after all.

Comment: @anon In short, you compute the matrix product $C^{-1}TB$ via row-reduction. This works because row-reducing an augmented matrix $[A\mid B]$ when $A$ is invertible amounts to left-multiplying it by its inverse. The same operations are applied to the right-hand side, so you end up with $[I\mid A^{-1}B]$. For this problem, you would row-reduce $[C\mid TB]$ to get $[I\mid C^{-1}TB]$.

Comment: Indeed, that's the efficient way of doing it. I thought that first dealing with one vector could make the procedure clear. Once you understand what to do, you can easily find the matrices describing the base changes and everything becomes easy and non-confusing.